# Locate an element in unsorted vector by using binary search on sorted vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, binary-search

I have been trying to get a position of an element in a vector using binary search only, no loops, nothing, just binary search functions from library `algorithm`.

Since binary search functions work only on sorted container types, I do not know how to get the position of searched element of the original vector, since in once vector is sorted, position of searched element will probably not be the same as in the original vector.

I made the code work with `std::find` but my main goal was to do it with binary search functions only.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1, 10, 100, -11, -112, -17, 44, -99, 99, 558};

    std::vector<int> sorted = v;
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end());

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;

    if(std::binary_search(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(), number) == false)
    {
        std::cout << "There is no entered number.";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Number is located on position: ";
        std::cout << std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), number) - v.begin();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example of output:

1°

```
Enter a number: 99
Number is located on position: 8
```

2°

```
Enter a number: -546
There is no entered number.
```

So if anyone could help me make this work with binary functions and not with `std::find` or give me few ideas, I would be very grateful.

Thanks :)

Comment: You cannot do a binary search on a non sorted data set.  The way the algorithm works relies on the data being sorted.

Comment: You can perform the same operations as in the sort simultaneously on a collection that contains the original indices, and look up the original location there after the search. This is slower than a linear search, so it's pretty pointless unless you need to search many times.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a binary search and have the result refer back to the original unsorted array -- you need to do an *index* sort and search -- instead of sorting and searching on a copy of the array, you operate on an array of indexes into the original array.  Something like:

```
std::vector<int> v {1, 10, 100, -11, -112, -17, 44, -99, 99, 558};

std::vector<int> sort_indexes(v.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    sort_indexes[i] = i;

std::sort(sort_indexes.begin(), sort_indexes.end(),
          [&v](int a, int b)->bool { return v[a] < v[b]; });

std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
int number;
std::cin >> number;

auto found = std::lower_bound(sort_indexes.begin(), sort_indexes.end(), number,
                              [&v](int a, int b)->bool { return v[a] < b; } );

if (found == sort_indexes.end() || v[*found] > number) {
    std::cout << "There is no entered number." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Number is located on position: " << *found << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::iota` to remove the explicit loop to fill `sort_indexes`.

Comment: This answers the original question, but I think  the plain `find()` is a better solution, at least for one-off search. It's O(n) vs. O(n log n). If you do many searches, this may be justified.

Answer (score 1):

As NathanOliver pointed out, it is not possible to do binary search on non-sorted data.

If your vector is guaranteed to have each number at most once and you don't want the order to change, you could keep a map that keeps the indices of each `int` your vector contains.

```
map<int, size_t> idxMap;
```

You could also use `std::find_if` which will do a linear search

```
int valueToFind;
vector<int>::const_iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [valueToFind](int entry) { return entry == valueToFind;)};
```

I would recommand the first option if you are not restricted in terms of memory and you want to do a significant number of searches.